# Estimating sample size for Mann Whitney U test

Tags: python, sample-size, statistical-power, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

I'm trying to estimate the required sample size for 80% power in an A/B testing, comparing user ratings with the Mann Whitney U test, and I'm having a problem with the power estimation.

I'm using this code to generate a dataset:

```
def sim_ratings(n, p):
    return np.random.choice(np.arange(5) + 1, size = (n,), p = p)
```

which I then compare. For example, I check the Type-1 error rate, and get this:

```
a = np.asarray([0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.4])

N_TRIALS = 10000

for N_SAMPLES in [10, 50, 100, 500]:
    p_values = np.asarray([mannwhitneyu(sim_ratings(N_SAMPLES, a), sim_ratings(N_SAMPLES, a), alternative = 'greater')[1]
                           for _ in range(N_TRIALS)])

    print(N_SAMPLES, np.sum(p_values < 0.05) / len(p_values))
```

which gives the expected output

```
10 0.0416
50 0.0508
100 0.0525
500 0.0523
```

But then when I try to calculate power, I run into a problem:

```
a = np.asarray([0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.4])
b = np.asarray([0.1, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.45])

N_TRIALS = 200
N_REPEAT = 10
ss = []
vv = []
for i in range(N_REPEAT):
    s = []
    v = []
    for N_SAMPLES in range(20, 2400, 20):
        p_values = np.asarray([mannwhitneyu(sim_ratings(N_SAMPLES, b), sim_ratings(N_SAMPLES, a), alternative = 'greater')[1]
                       for _ in range(N_TRIALS)])

        s.append(N_SAMPLES)
        v.append(np.sum(p_values < 0.05) / len(p_values))

    ss.append(s)
    vv.append(v)

plt.figure(figsize=(14,7))
for s,v in zip(ss, vv):
    plt.plot(s, v)
```

which renders the below graph.

[image: Graph of power]

Note the sudden dips to zero once the number of samples reaches a certain level. Is this a bug in my code or in the mannwhitneyu function from scipy? Is this a reasonable way to approximate the samples needed for a particular power level?

For what it's worth, I'm using Python 3.5 with SciPy 0.17.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem does not appear when replicating your code with more recent versions of Python (3.10), SciPy (1.11.1), and NumPy (1.22.3).

So it was likely a bug coming either from the SciPy implementation of the Mann-Whitney U test, or from the NumPy random.choice function, or from one of their dependencies. I suspect it was SciPy the culprit here, as when you wrote your question there were [some known issues](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/4933) with the SciPy implementation of the Mann-Whitney test (that have been fixed by now). But finding the exact mechanism by which the bug generated these sudden dips to 0 in your graph would probably require a non-negligible amount of time, for a limited interest now.

The small number of simulations (200 simulations for each of the 120 different sample sizes, with the simulations repeated 10 times separately) might have [slightly exacerbated the problem](https://debruine.github.io/post/how-many-sims/). But given that the 10 separate repetitions (represented by the different colored lines on the graph) follow the same pattern of dips to 0, back then we could have suspected that something else was going on than just a potentially too small number of simulations, even without the insight of an updated software.

Generally speaking, it may be a good idea to test a statistical routine against other statistical software or programming languages, in particular when you get results that seem off. It's also a good idea to [set a seed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639587/random-seed-what-does-it-do) when sharing code, to make sure other people can replicate your results exactly.

Below is a graph from a simulation similar to yours, in a different programming language (R), showing the power increasing as the sample size increases (the only difference is that I used 1x2000 simulations instead of 10x200 simulations like you did, but this difference does not really matter in the end). The graph shows the same pattern as yours, except that there are no dips to zero.  So you see that the problem you encountered back then was probably coming from some bug with SciPy or another Python library:

[image: A lineplot showing the increase of power as a function of sample size. It shows a pattern similar to the graph posted in the question, except that there are no dips to zero.]

Here is the R code to generate this graph (beware, the code is highly inefficient and takes something like 10 minutes to run, so it is meant just for illustrative purposes, not routine use):

```
a = c(0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.4)
b = c(0.1, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15, 0.45)
n.trial = 2000
sampsizes = c()
power = c()
set.seed(0)
for (samp.size in seq(20,2400,20)) {
  p.values = c()
  for (i in 1:n.trial) {
    samp.a = sample(c(1,2,3,4,5), size=samp.size, replace = T, prob = a)
    samp.b = sample(c(1,2,3,4,5), size=samp.size, replace = T, prob = b)
    res = wilcox.test(samp.b, samp.a, alternative = "greater", exact=F)  
    p = res$p.value
    p.values = c(p.values, p)
  }
  pw = sum(p.values <0.05)/length(p.values)
  power = c(power, pw)
  sampsizes = c(sampsizes, samp.size)
}
plot(sampsizes, power, type="l",xlab="sample size")
```